# get data from database and put it in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I tried to get data desk for spinner from my db, but it doesn't shows up; here's my code to set item in spinner;

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog after getting all desk
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Get desk
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>);
                Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                map.put("desk", parser.getValue(e, "desk"));
                mylist.add(map);
            }
            // Adding myList to ListView
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,new String[] { "desk" });
            s.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

when I tried to run it, it only show `desk` not my data in db, is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Just a little FYI, `onPostExecute` is called on the UI Thread.

Comment: @adneal I don't get it? it's my first time building application for android, I tried same code for listview and it works, but somehow it doesn't work for spinner?

Comment: I was saying it's unnecessary to call `runOnUiThread` because you're already running on the UI Thread in `onPostExecute`. Just a FYI, not really directed towards your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,mylist);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);                 
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```